# C# Powershell Cmdlet - Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.25.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm writing a Powershell cmdlet in C# for specific reasons. I'm trying to access the Azure Key Vault. I've followed examples, yet I keep getting the following error when running it from Powershell 7: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.25.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have the following code:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace My.PowerShell.Commands;
[Cmdlet( VerbsCommon.Get , "DGAMasterKeyPwd" )]
[OutputType( typeof( string ) )]
public class GetDGAMasterKeyPwdCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
   protected override async void ProcessRecord()
   {
       var vaultUri = $"https://XXXXXXX.vault.azure.net";
       var client = new SecretClient( new Uri( vaultUri ) , new DefaultAzureCredential( 
         ));
        var secret = await client.GetSecretAsync( "XXXXXXXXX" );

       WriteObject( secret );
   }
}
```

I know it is simplistic code, it is a proof of concept for something larger. I'm using the following NuGet packages: Azure.Identity, Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets, and Microsoft.Powershell.SDK. I'm also using .Net 6.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know whether it normally needs to be added separately, but note that there is a separate [`Azure.Core` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Core), which is what the error message complains about.

Comment: Could you please share your .csproj package reference file ?

Comment: @mklement0, I did try that, and got the same error

Comment: @Harshitha, Here you go:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="7.2.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: @Chris - There is no package related to `Azure.Core` in your `.csproj` file. As mentioned by `mklement0`, Install the `Azure.Core` Nuget package version `1.25.0` and check once.

Comment: @Harshitha, even including it did not help.

Comment: @Harshitha Azure.Identity depends on Azure.Core >= 1.25, and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets depends on Azure.Core >= 1.23.